# Chemistry behind cleaning with vinegar vs citric acid; do they work differently? Should I prepare the same pH solutions to compare them?

Tags: acid-base, everyday-chemistry, cleaning

I noticed a pack of "Mysterious Citric Acid" while out shopping so I picked it up to see what the big deal was. Several palates of the stuff had just arrived at a local outlet store. I figured that some chemical manufacturer had surplus so they quickly printed up some very promising looking packages.

Vinegar is often touted as a household cleaner, by it self at some dilution, or combined with various other household ingredients. I am wondering if the chemistry behind the use of a citric acid solution (when titrated properly, say for example to the same pH?) is the same as that of an acetic acid solution as far as household cleaning activities are concerned, or if they work differently or one is preferred over the other in some cases.

[image: "Mysterious Citric Acid" household cleaner]

**below:** click for full size

[image: "Mysterious Citric Acid" household cleaner] [image: "Mysterious Citric Acid" household cleaner]

Comment: Citrate chelates ionic calcium, accelerating dissolution of carbonate deposits.

Comment: Consider the more extreme case - should you compare cleaning properties at the same pH for acetic and hydrochloric acid ? E.g. at pH 2.5 ? The former would be much better, having much bigger neutralization capacity.  // Consider also citrate and acetate complexes with iron as rust removers on Wikipedia.

Comment: I like citric acid for household cleaning. I use it to descale my electric cattle the washing machine, the sink, the floors, the faucets, the everything. It smells a lot nicer than vinegar, and it usually does the job pretty well. Only thing left to wonder is: Whats so mysterious about it?!

Comment: Citric acid chelates  not only calcium, but many other metals, including manganese and iron found in some water supplies, which leave stains in kettles and on fixtures. It's also used in soil remediation: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1755-1315/896/1/012023/pdf . It might not be the most powerful chelating chemical, but it's comparatively safe and inexpensive.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン thanks, I'd never heard of it as a household product until I saw this for sale recently. By amazing coincidence have a bunch of hard yellow flakes of deposits I just collected from the inside of my electric hot water machine recently (it seems to have a non-stick coating inside) so I can compare vinegar and ctric acid solutions on them. [Chelation of calcium ions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/372982) sounds like something that happens to already-dissolved calcium; curious if and how either work to get them in to solution to begin with.

Comment: @BuckThorn ditto

Comment: I suppose I should have chosen my words more carefully. By dissolution I meant bringing a solid into solution. By accelerate I did not mean that the forward step of the reaction occurred faster, but rather that the product in solution is stabilized, inhibiting the reverse reaction (carbonate deposition).

Comment: Food grade citric acid is also a condiment: I purchased a bottle of it, with the name “sour salt”, at a local grocery store. I ended up using it for something else.